# Q.Watson Knowledge Studio Pre-annotate error

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-studio

When I try to run a Annotation in Watson Knowledge Studio I get the below error. "Error:Dictionary annotator process failed.:undefined" What could be the reason.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing that from the API? In any case, have you defined a dictionary? Are you maybe trying to annotate with the wrong type of annotator? If you're not using the WKS UI, I suggest to have a look there and check the different areas. As of the answer below, note there's a different between pre-annotation and annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for reporting your problem. We apologize for the inconvenience.

I quickly tried dictionary pre-annotation in my WKS instance and it worked for me. If your problem continues, could you please raise a ticket with detailed information such as URL of your WKS instance? So that Support team and Development team can take a look.

https://cloud.ibm.com/unifiedsupport/cases/add

Thank you,

Masashi Miyazaki